# How to play with the pitch of the PC Speaker using C#

Tags: c#, audio, windows-10, pitch

I am working on a learning project where I want to change the pitch of the incoming live audio. My logic is to just change the pitch of the speaker instead of altering the incoming audio.
I have found this chunk of code which works fine for the incoming audio from the microphone.
But mine is coming to another PC through LAN.

```
 private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Find sound capture devices and fill the cmbInput combo
            MMDeviceEnumerator deviceEnum = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
            mInputDevices = deviceEnum.EnumAudioEndpoints(DataFlow.Capture, DeviceState.Active);
            MMDevice activeDevice = deviceEnum.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Communications);

            foreach (MMDevice device in mInputDevices)
            {
                cmbInput.Items.Add(device.FriendlyName);
                if (device.DeviceID == activeDevice.DeviceID) cmbInput.SelectedIndex = cmbInput.Items.Count - 1;
            }

            //Find sound render devices and fill the cmbOutput combo
            activeDevice = deviceEnum.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Multimedia);
            mOutputDevices = deviceEnum.EnumAudioEndpoints(DataFlow.Render, DeviceState.Active);
            foreach (MMDevice device in mOutputDevices)
            {
                cmbOutput.Items.Add(device.FriendlyName);
                if (device.DeviceID == activeDevice.DeviceID) cmbOutput.SelectedIndex = cmbOutput.Items.Count - 1;
            }

        }
```

[This is the link of the complete project.](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1082074/Audio-Pitch-Shifter)

Could anyone can have a look on this code.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you need to search for information about writing / changing the driver or expanding the audio driver.

Comment: I saw on multiple videos that there are option for pitch adjusting in sound properties but unfortunately i am unable to find it on my PC.

Comment: What you are talking about just depends on the sound driver , try searching for the source of the sound drivers, their properties can be expanded and add audio frequency adjustment.